# How to protect a specific workbook only in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365

**What is the best way of protecting a specific Excel workbook?**

I have an inherited script that includes the following common lines at the end:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect "my-password"
ActiveWorkbook.Protect "my-password"
```

However, I've noticed that as the script can take a few minutes to run users often switch to a new unrelated workbook whilst it solves - whatever else they are working on. The password protection is then inherited by the unrelated workbook upon the completion of the macro - since whatever other Excel file the user is working within is now "Active" (presumably? this is my reading of the problem).

The above script is in a workbook that can be renamed to whatever the user chooses, and be saved in any number of directories. How can I ensure that only the original excel file is locked/unlocked by the Macro, when other workbooks are in use?

I am sure there are many ways to do this, but which is the most foolproof method?

NOTE: using office 365

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @Dean that is probably the syntax I need, will test. Cheers. So simple...

Comment: You might want to also store the `ActiveSheet` to a worksheet object in the event your users are changing workbooks., You will then be able to still reference that "ActiveSheet" regardless if they change workbooks.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately I get an "object required" error when using `ThisSheet.Protect`

Comment: Yeah `ThisSheet` does not exist. You will be able to use `ThisWorkbook` as a Workbook object. To use a Worksheet object I would recommend reading my comment above yours.

Comment: You can define the Workbook and Worksheets and use their names to Lock them. `Set wb = Thisworkbook` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dean's answers in the comments:

Early in the code (and in Worksheet_Change if appropriate) enter the following to define your sheet as an object (named default_ws in my case):

```
Set default_ws = ActiveSheet
```

When you are ready to lock your sheet or workbook you can then use:

```
default_ws.Protect "password-here" 'protect your sheet
ThisWorkbook.Protect "password-here" 'protect your workbook
```

Also note:

You could also define your workbook as an object as follows if desired:

```
Set default_wb = ActiveWorkbook
```